# issues with Substitution Cipher code in Python

Tags: python, encryption

Sorry for the lengthy code, I have tried for a while to fix the errors occurring in the main function. Not sure where to go from here.

- Edited to fix indentation issues, now the function runs but the command
  "Enter a command (getKey, changeKey, encrypt, decrypt, quit):" repeats regardless of the input apart from getKey. When getKey is input, I get the error "'SubstitutionCipher' object has no attribute 'getKey'"
- Second edit to class SubstitutionCipher allowed the function to at least give one output for the getKey.

```
#A global constant defining the alphabet
LCLETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

#function to check if given key is valid or not

def isLegalKey(key):
    return ( len(key) == 26 and all ( [ch in key for ch in LCLETTERS ] ) )

#function to generate random key
def makeRandomKey():
    lst = list( LCLETTERS )
    random.shuffle( lst )
    return ''.join( lst )
  
  

class SubstitutionCipher:
    def __init__ (self, key = makeRandomKey() ):
        self._key = key
  
    def getKey( self ):
        return self._key
  
    def setKey( self, newKey ):
        self._key = newKey
  
    def encryptText( self, plaintext ):
        alphabet = LCLETTERS
        key = SubstitutionCipher.getKey(self)
        text = plaintext

        result = ""
        for letter in text:
            if letter.lower() in alphabet:
                result += key[alphabet.find(letter.lower())]
            else:
                result += letter

        return result
  
def decryptText( self, ciphertext):
    alphabet = LCLETTERS
    key = SubstitutionCipher.getKey(self)
    text = ciphertext

    result = ""
    for letter in text:
        if letter.lower() in key:
            result += alphabet[key.find(letter.lower())]
        else:
            result += letter

        return result
  
def main():
    flag =0
    cipherFun = SubstitutionCipher()
    while(flag ==0):
        print("Enter a command (getKey, changeKey, encrypt, decrypt, quit): ")
        str = input()
  
        if(str == 'getKey'):
            print(cipherFun.getKey())
  
        elif(str == 'changeKey'):
            temp =0
    while(temp == 0):
        print("Enter a valid cipher key, 'random' for a random key, or 'quit' to quit: ")
        cipher = input()
        if(cipher == 'random'):
            print(makeRandomKey())
            temp = 1
            break;
        elif(cipher == 'quit'):
            temp = 1
            break;
        elif(isLegalKey(cipher) == False):
            print("Illegal key entered. Try again")
    else:
        cipherFun.setKey(cipher)
        print("New cipher key: ", cipherFun.getKey())
        temp = 1
        if(str == 'encrypt'):
            print("Enter a text to encrypt: ")
            str = input()
            res = cipherFun.encryptText(str)
            print("The encrypted text is: ", res)
  
        elif(str == 'decrypt'):
            print("Enter a text to decrypt: ")
            str = input()
            res = cipherFun.decryptText(str)
            print("The decrypted text is: ", res)
  
        elif(str == 'quit'):
            print("Thanks for visiting!")
            flag =1
  
  
        else:
            print("command not recognized. Try again")
  
  
  
  
main()
```

I am not sure if these are issues with the syntax, indentation, other features, or a combination of these. Id appreciate some insight because I have been trying to fix this for days. Issues are currently that the breaks are outside the loop, when changing the indentation i get an error saying unexpected indentation.

Comment: What errors do you see, and in which lines?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that every line starting with `if(str == 'getKey'):` needs to be indented so they are part of the `while` loop.  Also PLEASE NOTE that `if` statements in Python do not need parentheses.

Comment: The section that validates `cipher` also needs to be indented to be part of that inner `while` loop.

Comment: You have huge indentation problems, at least as presented here.  The member functions in SubstitutionCipher must be indented as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with the indentation fixed, plus a few miscellaneous fixes.  This seems to work.

```
import random
#A global constant defining the alphabet
LCLETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

#function to check if given key is valid or not

def isLegalKey(key):
    return ( len(key) == 26 and all ( [ch in key for ch in LCLETTERS ] ) )

#function to generate random key
def makeRandomKey():
    lst = list( LCLETTERS )
    random.shuffle( lst )
    return ''.join( lst )



class SubstitutionCipher:
    def __init__ (self, key = makeRandomKey() ):
        self._key = key

    def getKey( self ):
        return self._key

    def setKey( self, newKey ):
        self._key = newKey

    def encryptText( self, plaintext ):
        alphabet = LCLETTERS
        key = self._key
        text = plaintext

        result = ""
        for letter in text:
            if letter.lower() in alphabet:
                result += key[alphabet.find(letter.lower())]
            else:
                result += letter

        return result

    def decryptText( self, ciphertext):
        alphabet = LCLETTERS
        key = self._key
        text = ciphertext

        result = ""
        for letter in text:
            if letter.lower() in key:
                result += alphabet[key.find(letter.lower())]
            else:
                result += letter

        return result

#main function
def main():
    flag =0
    cipherFun = SubstitutionCipher()
    while flag ==0:
        print("Enter a command (getKey, changeKey, encrypt, decrypt, quit): ")
        str = input()

        if str == 'getKey':
            print(cipherFun.getKey())

        elif str == 'changeKey':
            while True:
                print("Enter a valid cipher key, 'random' for a random key, or 'quit' to quit: ")
                cipher = input()

                if cipher == 'random':
                    cipherFun.setKey(makeRandomKey())
                    break
                elif cipher == 'quit':
                    break
                elif isLegalKey(cipher) == False:
                    print("Illegal key entered. Try again")
                else:
                    cipherFun.setKey(cipher)
                    print("New cipher key: ", cipherFun.getKey())
                    break
        elif str == 'encrypt':
            print("Enter a text to encrypt: ")
            str = input()
            res = cipherFun.encryptText(str)
            print("The encrypted text is: ", res)

        elif str == 'decrypt':
            print("Enter a text to decrypt: ")
            str = input()
            res = cipherFun.decryptText(str)
            print("The decrypted text is: ", res)

        elif str == 'quit':
            print("Thanks for visiting!")
            flag =1

        else:
            print("command not recognized. Try again")

main()
```